# Unable To Retrieve $_GET['id'] Value?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, get

I am unable to retrieve the id from the $_GET variable. I am trying to update a table in a database with a specific id. The thing is, i can see the id on the address bar, but cannot retrieve it via $_GET this is the code. Here i am only sharing the part of the code. kindly check it and guide me.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';  
$id= $_GET['product_id'];

$select_query = "select * from products LEFT JOIN product_description 
                ON products.product_id='".$_GET['product_id']."' and 
                product_description.product_id='".$_GET['product_id']."' 
                where products.product_id='".$_GET['product_id']."'     ";

if(!$select_query_run = mysql_query($select_query))
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
else


Notice: Undefined index: product_id in
F:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\update_single_product.php on line 36
```

and if i use `$id` instead, it gives me the error on the 4th line.

```
/cms/update_single_product.php?product_id=159
```

**

> I made the few changes and its working now. I still don't know how it 
>   got fixed but its working :)

**

Comment: please post the url you see on your browser address bar

Comment: http://localhost/cms/update_single_product.php?product_id=159

Comment: Could you try dumping out the `$_GET` array to see what *is* in it, eg `var_dump($_GET); exit;`?

Comment: is there any modification in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Also, MySQL extension **bad** (deprecated), PDO **good**

Comment: array(1) { ["product_id"]=> string(3) "159" } 159

Comment: Then probably you have unknowingly written some invisible character. Delete `$_GET['product_id']` in line 36 and rewrite it again (do not cut & paste).

Comment: The error location and the code you've shown here don't match. If you want us to help, provide the code up until that line.

Comment: Its working now. I made the few changes and its working now. I still don't know how it got fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if $_GET['product_id'] is set first. You also have $_GET['product_id'] defined in a variable. Use it on your query, and don't forget to protect all inputs from mysql injections.

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['product_id']);

$select_query=  "SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN product_description ON products.product_id='".$id."' and product_description.product_id='".$id."' where products.product_id='".$id."'";
```

You could try to echo $id and see what happens.

On a side note; MySQL is deprecated. You should use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: its given me the same id number that it is showing in the Address bar

Comment: Try checking if the variable is set first. if (isset($_GET['product_id'])) { //do stuff that requires 'product_id' }

Answer (score 1):

Use isset() to avoid problems.

```
if(isset($_GET['product_id'])) {
  $id= $_GET['product_id'];

} else {
  $id = 1;
}
// code here
```

Using this you can avoid action without get value also.